# How can I fix this "cannot load such file" error?

Tags: ruby

I'm applying to AppAcademy and need to do some exercises so I downloaded the ZIP as required from https://github.com/appacademy/test-first-ruby

I saved the file to my desktop and ran `bundle install` while inside the folder like the. Then through the terminal I go to the spec folder where the exercises are located and run the following command:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
Macintosh-2:spec Michael$ bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb
/Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core 2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/Michael/Desktop/RubyCodes/test-first-ruby-master/spec/spec/00_hello_spec.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `each'
    from /Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1065:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in `run'
    from /Users/Michael/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I have ruby 2.1.3, bundler 1.7.9, and rspec 2.99.1.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to find the missing file yourself - from terminal, run `cat /Users/Michael/Desktop/RubyCodes/test-first-ruby-master/spec/spec/00_hello_spec.rb`. Also, just to make sure, did you extract the zip file first?

Comment: I did extract the zip file.  I know where the file is but not sure how to fix the error..

Comment: Oh I ran the command you posted but it ends up saying no such file or directory :/

Comment: Looks like you run `bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb` in spec folder, try `bundle exec rspec 00_hello_spec.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be running the command from the wrong directory. Consider your error message:

```
`load': cannot load such file -- /Users/Michael/Desktop/RubyCodes/test-first-ruby-master/spec/spec/00_hello_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

and notice that the `spec` directory appears twice in the error message's file path. This implies the existence of a `spec` directory within a `spec` directory. It's more likely that there is just one `spec` directory. Within your same terminal context, run the following command to bring you up one directory level:

```
cd ..
```

then try your command again:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb
```

You can think of `cd` as standing for "change directory" while `..` represents one directory level above the current level (the current level is represented with a `.`).

Alternatively, you can run the following command from within the `spec` directory:

```
bundle exec rspec 00_hello_spec.rb
```

Comment: For some reason going up one directory from spec and entering the command "bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb" works but while in the spec folder and trying to run the command "bundle exec rspec 00_hello_spec.rb doesn't work.  Anyway thanks so much.